# Mage registry key "_singleton/customer/session" already exists

Tags: magento-1.9, php

In magento 1.9.x

```
 "Mage registry key "_singleton/customer/session" already exists"
```

I have tried all possible solution from google but didn't worked any help would be great.

Comment: [Mage registry key “_singleton/” already exists error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608376/mage-registry-key-singleton-already-exists-error)

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined any observer in your module, then check the observer definition in **config.xml** file under **app/code/[codepool]/[package]/[module]/etc** folder. It should look like this:

```
<events>
    <event_name>
        <observers>
            <some_unique_identifier>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Class_Name</class>
                <method>method_name</method>
            </some_unique_identifier>
        </observers>
    </event_name>
</events>
```

where:

- "**some_unique_identifier**" can be any unique string.
- "**event_name**" should be the name of the event you want to observe.
- "**Class_Name**" should be the class name in which your observer function exists.
- "**method_name**" should be your observer function name.